# PostgreSQL Instead of update rule with multiple queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, sql-update

I am having problems with INSTEAD OF UPDATE rule with multiple queries in Postgres - currently version 9.2.4 but I think I had the similar issue with previous versions too. I have a rule with three queries (inserts/updates) and some of them sometimes are not executed. And it seems that it may depend on order of those queries. Unfortunately it is really hard to debug as it sometimes works fine. I did not find any limitation or so in official documentation.

I have three tables (A,B and AB), where A and B contains data and some "tag" and timestamp of "tagging". Table AB just contains relation between A and B but unfortunately only between some data from A and some data from B. Tagging means that the data has been verified by operator and that they are OK, there are many reasons for tagging while one is that the data in A and B matches. (I know that the schema is not ideal but that is out of my reach to modify).

I have view view_ab that tries to match the data from A to B and the view has one rule:

```
CREATE RULE view_AB_rl AS ON UPDATE TO public.view_AB
DO INSTEAD (
 INSERT INTO AB (keyA,keyB) VALUES (new.keyA, new.keyB);
 UPDATE B SET tag = new.tag, 
    taggingTS = LEAST(now(), ( SELECT B.taggingTS FROM B WHERE b.keyB=new.keyB))
  WHERE b.keyB=new.keyB;
UPDATE A SET tag = new.tag, taggingTS = now()  WHERE A.keyA = new.keyA;
 );
```

The idea is that the operator does the SELECT * from view_AB (usually with additional filter conditions), checks if the pairing is OK and does UPDATE view_AB SET tag='something' (with the same filters). The rule should distribute the data into A,B and AB and should update the taggingTS in both tables A and B (in B it should not change the taggingTS if it is already present).

While it sometimes works exactly like it should, sometimes it executes only the first two queries. Basically it inserts binding record into AB, it updates B tag and tagTS but does not update A at all... And of course such problems cause a lot of problems as the data gets out of sync...

I am considering changing it to trigger as it seems to be a viable option too but first I would like to at least understand why the rule approach is not working. I like the idea that I create a view as combination of data and create rule for distributing changes back into underlying data while trigger would be more "if something changes do something extra"...

Comment: Maybe the update does not affect any A rows because `... WHERE A.keyA = new.keyA;` does not address any existing rows (key-update) ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are foreign keys on AB that would fail if the keyA would not be in A or keyB would not be in B. And the record is definetly present in both A and B when I am checking what is going on and ist OK except in A it does not have the tag related fields set...

Comment: So AB is just an ordinary bridge-table. BTW It helps to add the table definitions.

Comment: Exactly. Thats why I named it AB and I said that it just contains relation between A and B. I had to simplify the names and fields a lot so thats why I did not include their definitions but rather described them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to combination of rule and triggers and it seems to be working now - at least I did not find any data out of sync yet as I did with rule only approach.

The idea is to keep the query that updates the AB table:

```
CREATE RULE view_AB_rl AS ON UPDATE TO public.view_AB
DO INSTEAD (
    INSERT INTO AB (keyA,keyB,tag) VALUES (new.keyA, new.keyB,tag);
)
```

This unfortunately means that I had to add the tag field to the AB table.

And then I have the trigger (after every row) on AB that basically does the two remaining queries.